# Android how to debug google-breakbad crash

Tags: android, debugging, crash, libc

A user from my Android app told me the app crashes sometimes and thankfully I had put a feature to let them "save" the logcat to a file so that I can have a look.

but the crash didn't have a single stack trace just this:

```
12-02 19:41:10.213  6950  9516 D MYTAG   : task pool-32-thread-13 doing action 1
12-02 19:41:10.219  6950  9526 D HELLO   : task pool-32-thread-14 is going action2
12-02 19:41:10.219  6950  9526 D HELLO   : task pool-32-thread-14 is doing action 1
--------- beginning of crash
12-02 19:41:10.222  6950  9532 F libc    : FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE
12-02 19:41:10.245  6950  9550 F libc    : FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE
12-02 19:41:10.245  6950  9509 F libc    : FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE
12-02 19:41:10.255  6950  9555 F libc    : FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE
12-02 19:41:10.257  6950  9516 F libc    : FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE
....
[good amount of other logs coming from my app]
...
12-02 19:41:10.263  6950  9526 F libc    : FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE
[good amount of other logs coming from my app]
12-02 19:41:10.488  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
12-02 19:41:10.488  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: V WebView:54.0.2840.85
12-02 19:41:10.488  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: O A arm 04 armv7l htc/htc_asia_hk/htc_m8:6.0/MRA58K/683910.1:user/release-keys
12-02 19:41:10.488  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: P webview
12-02 19:41:10.488  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: G OpenGL ES 3.0 V@136.0 AU@ (GIT@I3fa967cfef)|Qualcomm|Adreno (TM) 330
12-02 19:41:10.517  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: H 12C00000 FFFF1000 0169 415E9000 875BA000 0C:3B 0D:1C 0E:1C 0F:58 10:2C 11:1A 12:0E 13:18 14:05 15:06 16:09 17:07 18:0A 19:08 1A:03 1B:01 1E:01
12-02 19:41:10.517  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: S 0 6B12D6F0 6B12D000 00002000
12-02 19:41:10.529  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: S 6B12D000 
...
...
...
2-02 19:41:10.535  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M B6F79000 00000000 00005000 3AC2FF72A56F89E753909FE87EC9E5B90 app_process32
12-02 19:41:10.536  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M 73C3F000 02256000 0199B000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot.oat
12-02 19:41:10.536  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M 8F512000 00000000 00006000 A818C3C96A1E511DE2821246BCEAEC250 gralloc.msm8974.so
12-02 19:41:10.536  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M 907EC000 00007000 00004000 000000000000000000000000000000000 1470286953684.dex (deleted)
12-02 19:41:10.536  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M 91914000 00000000 00009000 716F22A588C1891B19C5583863000E2F0 eglsubAndroid.so
12-02 19:41:10.536  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M 922E7000 00141000 000F6000 000000000000000000000000000000000 base.odex
12-02 19:41:10.536  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M 927CE000 00000000 00004000 AD1CA1E05260AD3B0FEBE8137AA109FA0 libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
12-02 19:41:10.536  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M 92FB1000 00378000 0027A000 000000000000000000000000000000000 DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_pro
....
12-02 19:41:10.543  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M B6EBE000 00000000 0002A000 BB50710C1D4E5E12FAC8358FDBD239300 libbinder.so
12-02 19:41:10.543  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M B6EF0000 00000000 00008000 77D8F6CE0EA90702417E8C2D00E5DD0C0 liblog.so
12-02 19:41:10.543  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M B6EFC000 00000000 0001B000 46EBB3252B06AE9C6065FB25F0D0178D0 libutils.so
12-02 19:41:10.543  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M B6F1A000 00000000 0000F000 7421921873D47767CA00D46D01278D650 libcutils.so
12-02 19:41:10.543  9668  9532 F google-breakpad: M B6F58000 00000000 0001C000 379C3F393D7D0A33EAE953A91AEDF7830 linker
12-02 19:41:10.870  9675  9454 F google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
12-02 19:41:15.164  6950  9454 W google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
12-02 19:41:15.164  6950  9454 W google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
12-02 19:41:15.164  6950  9454 W google-breakpad: MY-APP-VERSION
12-02 19:41:15.164  6950  9454 W google-breakpad: BUILD-NUMBER
12-02 19:41:15.164  6950  9454 W google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
12-02 19:41:19.887  9751  9751 I MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
12-02 19:41:19.887  9751  9751 I MultiDex: install
12-02 19:41:19.887  9751  9751 I MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
```

when the crash occurs a multi-thread algo is in action so it is VERY hard for me to know which line exactly triggers the crash. As you can see when the crash first start then the algo continue to work a print debug line in between...

some indication:

> - a single goole mapfragment is shown
> - there is an AdMob banner at the bottom
> - the crash occurs during the multi-thread algo
> - the crash does NOT occurs after a specific action
> - the uses otto bus to communicate from thread to MAP ui
> - Upon receiving an event the map display or remove things on the map
> - I dont have a memory dump
> - I have no idea what is "libc    : FORTIFY: FD_SET"

How can I go about debuging this? Where do I start?